# Can you run a function on initialization in c?

Tags: c, initialization, portability

Is there an mechanism or trick to run a function when a program loads?

What I'm trying to achieve...

```
void foo(void)
{
}

register_function(foo);
```

but obviously register_function won't run.

so a trick in C++ is to use initialization to make a function run

something like

```
int throwaway = register_function(foo);
```

but that doesn't work in C.  So I'm looking for a way around this using standard C (nothing platform / compiler specific )

Comment: because I want a number .c files, and I don't want people to have to remember to go put the register function in main....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using GCC, you can do this with a `constructor` function attribute, eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() __attribute__((constructor));

void foo() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

int main() { return 0; }
```

There is no portable way to do this in C, however.

If you don't mind messing with your build system, though, you have more options. For example, you can:

```
#define CONSTRUCTOR_METHOD(methodname) /* null definition */

CONSTRUCTOR_METHOD(foo)
```

Now write a build script to search for instances of CONSTRUCTOR_METHOD, and paste a sequence of calls to them into a function in a generated .c file. Invoke the generated function at the start of `main()`.

Comment: nice, its what I want, but I was hoping for something more standard C

Comment: bdonlan's solution doesn't use C++. Read over it again; it's merely GCC-specific.

Comment: he changed his answer, it used to have a C++ soloution in it as well

Comment: build script is a bit of a hassle as this is part of a framework that should be pretty seamless to integrate into your project.  I could do evilness.....  I could make a struct (using a macro) and put a magic string and a function pointer in it and then at run time look through memory for the magic string and recover the struct :-)

Comment: That's going to be even less portable than using the GCC constructor extension, I think. Moreover, there's a chance of a false positive resulting in a REALLY hard to debug error.

Comment: What compilers are you trying to target btw?

Comment: ideally, most of the embedded compilers (which are a mish mash of weirdness at the best of times) as well as the more standard MS / GCC compilers

Answer (score 3):

Standard C does not support such an operation.  If you don't wish to use compiler specific features to do this, then your next best bet might be to create a global static flag that is initialized to false.  Then whenever someone invokes one of your operations that require the function pointer to be registered, you check that flag.  If it is false you register the function then set the flag to true.  Subsequent calls then won't have to perform the registration.  This is similar to the lazy instantiation used in the OO Singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of doing this although gcc provides a `constructor` attribute for functions.

The usual way of ensuring some pre-setup has been done (other than a simple variable initialization to a compile time value) is to make sure that all functions requiring that pre-setup. In other words, something like:

```
static int initialized = 0;
static int x;

int returnX (void) {
    if (!initialized) {
        x = complicatedFunction();
        initialized = 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

This is best done in a separate library since it insulates you from the implementation.

Comment: yeah....  however in my case I'm wanting a pre-setup where a function will be registered and stored in a list..... then later on something will go through that list running the registered functions.   Currently that means each function needs to be explicitly added in some central location.   I was wanting to find a trick where the function can be registered at the point of declaration