# How to initialize a GNU C global register variable

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

[GNU C global register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html) can't have initializers.  This won't compile as C or C++:

```
// at global scope.
register int i asm ("r12") = 10;
```

gives ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include%3Cstdio.h%3E%0Aregister+int+i+asm+(%22r12%22)+%3D+10%3B++//how+to+initialize+i+here+itself%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++i%3D10%3B%0A++++register+int+i%3D20%3B%0A++++printf(%22%25d%5Cn%22,i)%3B%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++extern+int+i%3B%0A++++++++printf(%22%25d%5Cn%22,i)%3B%0A++++%7D+++%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:34.283198717546206,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'171')),options:'-O3+-march%3Dsandybridge',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:33.57195166118412,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:33.57195166118412,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'171')),options:'-O3+-march%3Dsandybridge',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:32.144849621269685,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)) `error: global register variable has initial value`.  Local scope is fine of course, but GNU C *local* register variables are a very different thing.  (Only guaranteed to do anything in terms of interaction with Extended `asm()` statements.)

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
register int i asm ("r12");  //how to initialize i here?
int main()
{
    i=10;            // Would rather avoid this workaround
    printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

How to initialize `i` at global scope, not waiting until the top of main?

Comment: You can't do it there, but you can use a [constructor function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081845/547981) You didn't tag it but I assume you use gcc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486715/why-cant-register-variables-be-made-global

Comment: I want to initialize it because. I want 'i' to be accessed by other library or object files. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081845/547981 is not working with my gcc.@Jester

Comment: Declaring `register` variables doesn't make much sense 1) at file scope 2) at all. gcc might allow all manner of weird features, but that doesn't mean that those features make sense.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just want to initialize 'i' variable before main@thebusybee

Comment: If you use `libc` functions, global register variables are not necessarily going to work.  The manual is quite clear: using global register variables changes the ABI and thus makes your code incompatible with any libraries.

Comment: It is definitely *not* possible to put a global or static variable in a register. But if i is an automatic variable, there is no problem. `register int i asm ("r12")=25;` is perfectly valid if declared *in* a function. As already mentioned, its usefulness is debatable.

Comment: Yes,we can't initialize - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html#Global-Register-Variables

Comment: **Global register variables cannot have initial values, because an executable file has no means to supply initial contents for a register. **

Comment: Well, what **is** your gcc version? Also, how does it not work?

Comment: @AlainMerigot: that's incorrect, GNU C does allow global scope asm-register variables.  You just can't statically initialize them *in C* (and apparently not C++ either).  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html

Comment: @Jester ,I am getting garbage values https://www.onlinegdb.com/B1CjtMMtr

Comment: No idea why my comments keep getting deleted, but here it is one final time. Using the [correct syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081845/547981) the constructor is invoked but the `__libc_csu_init` that calls it happens to overwrite the `r12` value. That is because of what [fuz quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuz): _"using global register variables changes the ABI and thus makes your code incompatible with any libraries"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't initialize a global register variable.

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html#Global-Register-Variables) states this:

> Global register variables cannot have initial values, because an executable file has no means to supply initial contents for a register.

Also note the paragraph below:

> When selecting a register, choose one that is normally saved and restored by function calls on your machine. This ensures that code which is unaware of this reservation (such as library routines) will restore it before returning.

You should not use `r12`, it is not saved across calls.

Comment: In x86-64 System V, `r12..r15` are call-preserved.  I guess you're assuming this is ARM, where yes `r12` is call-clobbered.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was assuming ARM.